# Update QueryExpression

Tags: c#, sdk

Fiz um select para trazer todas as entidades as quais contém o campo "se_customdate" como null. Até aí, sem problemas. Entretanto, agora, necessito atribuir o valor da variável "createdon" aos campos nulos, mas eu não estou conseguindo progredir no código.

1: Pensei em montar um foreach, onde toda entidade retornada como null, passará pelo laço e receberá o valor de createdon, ficou assim:

```
foreach(Entity etn in ec){  
               entity["se_customdate"] = "createdon";
            }
```

o foreach aponta o erro:

> "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection' because 'microsoft.xrm.sdk.entitycollection' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'.

Segue código utilizado por mim durante todo o percurso:

```
public class PreencheCampoDataHistorico : CodeActivity
{       
    private string _activityName = "Preencher Campo de Data Historico";
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
    {
        ITracingService tracingService = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();

        if (tracingService == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve tracing service.");
        }

        tracingService.Trace("Entered " + _activityName + ".Execute(), Activity Instance Id: {0}, Workflow Instance Id: {1}",
        executionContext.ActivityInstanceId,
        executionContext.WorkflowInstanceId);

        // Create the context  
        IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();

        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Failed to retrieve workflow context.");
        }

        tracingService.Trace(_activityName + ".Execute(), Correlation Id: {0}, Initiating User: {1}",
        context.CorrelationId,
        context.InitiatingUserId);

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {                          
            Entity entity = new Entity("se_historicodelicenciamento");
            ColumnSet attributes = new ColumnSet(new string[] { "se_customdate","createdon" });

            QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = entity.LogicalName,
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet (new string[] {"name","se_customdate","createdon"}),

                Criteria = 
                {
                    FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And,
                    Conditions = 
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression
                        {
                            AttributeName = "se_customdatehistory",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = {String.Empty}
                        }
                    }                       
            }              
        };  

            EntityCollection ec = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

            foreach(Entity etn in ec){                                                                     
                entity["se_customdate"] = "createdon";
            }
```

Solicito ideias, novas formas de abordagem/métodos de resolução ou até mesmo alguma luz de como prosseguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é porque EntityCollection não é uma lista, ele é um objeto que contém uma lista. o Foreach só consegue iterar dentro de coleção com o método GetEnumerator(), implementada por IEnumerable. Tente:

```
foreach(Entity etn in ec.Entities){  
    entity["se_customdate"] = "createdon";
}
```

O segundo erro você resolveu?

Comment: Caramba, entendi! Eu estava achando que eu tinha que colocar o GetEnumerator() em algum lugar das linhas de código, haha.
Então, o segundo erro era porque eu estava passando a atribuição como "secustomdate" += "createdon"; Dei uma pesquisada e achei um cara que utiliza a atribuição como entity["se_customdate"] = "createdon";

Muito obrigado, Gabriel!